# Module authorize for Customize user, group & module profile

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I had created my own user profile as well as a group profile and module profile which user can assign user to a group and define which user group can access to which module.In order to check user access, can i use Custom Authorize Attribute? or i have to write my own validate access function and apply it in my controller action?

Comment: Please take care when you add tags. [tag:asp.net-mvc] shall only be used for the old legacy ASP.NET MVC frameworks. ASP.NET Core MVC is a complete rewrite and redesign of the stack, made in mind to run on multiple platforms whereas ASP.NET MVC is tightly coupled to IIS. The correct tag is [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]

Comment: noted with thanks.

Comment: You don't give enough information to advise you. How are you serializing an identity? Are you using the built in cookie middleware, or are you rolling your own middleware?

Comment: Instead of using default user Identity, role, member and etc, I created my own user profile together with user group and module profile. Then once user logged in, i will keep user information in session with the purpose to check their access at controller. So any suggestion that how can i do this validation?